# How do I handle unable to send email on Laravel 4 on non existing email address

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I just discovered that my Laravel 4 script does not work if I pass a non existing email address on Mail:Queue(). The email address has a valid format, i.e. "@" sign after the name, domain after "@". A sample would be "johndoesnotexist@notexistemail.com". The format is valid even though "notexistemail.com" does not exist at all.

Here's the code snippet:

```
$email_data = array('color' => 'Red');
$email_company = 'johndoesnotexist@notexistemail.com';
$email_name = 'john doe';
Mail::queue('emails.form1', $email_data, function($message) use($email_company, $email_name) {
    $message->to($email_company, $email_name)->subject('Hello John');
});
```

But if I pass an existing email address, the script works. I need to handle this kind of error, i.e. log the error in laravel.log. How do I code it?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. When you say your script does not work do you mean it is throwing an exception?

Comment: Hi, I'm using AJAX to call the script. I notice the call does not respond. On Chrome console, I see internal error 500. But when I replace with an existing email, the script works. Thanks

Comment: I'm currently checking this out, https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#failed-jobs

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that an exception is getting thrown in which case you could try and catch this and then log the problem email address. Something like this:-

```
try {
    $email_data = array('color' => 'Red');
    $email_company = 'johndoesnotexist@notexistemail.com';
    $email_name = 'john doe';
    Mail::queue('emails.form1', $email_data, function($message) use($email_company, $email_name) {
        $message->to($email_company, $email_name)->subject('Hello John');
    });
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::error('Failed to send email to ' . $email_company);
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks